# Void Linux - Audio not working in blank install

Tags: linux, audio

I have been trying to set up void properly, and everything has been pretty smooth, except this.

All I have installed is dwm, otherwise, this is a blank install.

I installed PulseSound and a bunch of alsa packages, to no result. I also tried using alsamixer, to no effect.

Some info I found: Aplay -l returns three sound cards, which are all labeled as zero, and are identical except for the "device" part

Do I need to do something special to get this working? Any info would be appreciated!